# NoSuchMethod error on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-admin

My Google App Engine server runs:

- The Firebase Admin SDK
- Google Cloud Endpoints v2

After updating to Endpoints v2 recently (unsure if related), I have been getting this error on the server while my mobile app:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.checkNotDeleted(FirebaseApp.java:314)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getOptions(FirebaseApp.java:260)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:74)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:61)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:52)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$FirebaseAuthService.<init>(FirebaseAuth.java:316)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseAuth.java:98)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseAuth.java:85)
at com.project.apis.UserAPI.verifyUserIDToken(MyAPI.java:100)
```

Can anyone advise? Other reports have suggested updating the Guava dependency in my `pom.xml`, but I am not even using Guava:

- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3880
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when there are 2 incompatible versions of guava in the classpath. Firebase uses one version (v20.0), and the Google App Engine libraries use an older version (v18.0 I believe). You can check the dependency tree using the `mvn dependency:tree` command, and then add an exclusion rule to the older version.

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/50
- [NoSuchMethodError: While integrating Firebase with app engine app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170175/nosuchmethoderror-while-integrating-firebase-with-app-engine-app)

Comment: The dependency tree only lists Guava once (com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile). Could it be another problem?

Comment: Firebase needs 20.0. Try adding it to the classpath, and removing 19.0.

Comment: It is still somehow getting bound to the 19.0 version. Can you post your dependency tree?

Comment: Also make sure that the web archive in your `target/` directory (the artifacts that get deployed to App Engine) has only guava 20.0 in `WEB-INF/lib`. Maven is notorious for caching these stuff, and you may want to run `mvn clean` to nuke the old artifacts, and rebuild the project with guava 20.0.